react-native-compat: Application module is not available
I'm trying to connect wallets using the walletconnect module, but I get a react-native-compat: The application module is not available.
this is my code Home.jsx
import '@walletconnect/react-native-compat';
import { WagmiConfig } from 'wagmi';
import { mainnet, polygon, arbitrum, base, optimism, zkSync } from 'viem/chains';
import { createWeb3Modal, defaultWagmiConfig, W3mButton, Web3Modal } from '@web3modal/wagmi-react-native';
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const projectId = "my_project_id";

const metadata = {
    name: 'GUMMY LIVE',
    description: 'This is gummy live wallet connect.',
    url: 'https://web3modal.com',
    icons: ['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37784886']
};

const chains = [mainnet, polygon, arbitrum, base, optimism, zkSync];

const wagmiConfig = defaultWagmiConfig({ chains, projectId, metadata });

createWeb3Modal({
    projectId,
    chains,
    wagmiConfig
});

and this my depedencies on package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.5",
    "@walletconnect/react-native-compat": "^2.13.0",
    "@web3modal/wagmi-react-native": "^1.3.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^10.7.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-compat": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-router-native": "^6.23.1",
    "viem": "^1.21.4",
    "wagmi": "^1.4.13",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  }
}


but the application still work correctly with show the error warning. can anyone help me to solve the error?

Try running:
npx expo install expo-application
